# Android ListView with custom item

Tags: java, android

I want to do a `ListView` with a custom items. The general item is a full width image with two text views, a other image like a icon.

Something like:

[image]

What it's the best way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried searching before coming here? There must be at least a dozen tutorials on this

Comment: i tried but cantd do it as i want. sry

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your own adapter for `ListView` by extending `BaseAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter`, etc. And there you can write your own implementation of `getView()` method which is responsible for the view of every item in your `ListView`.

Inside `getView()` method you can just inflate view from your XML with layout and populate it with the needed data.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go .. This will at least navigate you to some extent. I am having one image, three textviews in the group. In your case, there's one image view and two textviews and that's the only difference here.

Here's how I implemented it:

Step 1: In the MainActivity, I have made a custom adapter which is having 5 things, one Imageview and 4 textviews.

Here's the code:

```
public class ListViewExample extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> QuestionForSliderMenu = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> NAME = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> STATE = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> LATITUDE = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> LONGITUDE = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customlistView1);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, QuestionForSliderMenu);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        try {
            yourjson();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Just for example. You can do anything to get in your array list.
    public void yourjson() {

        NAME = new ArrayList<String>();
        STATE = new ArrayList<String>();
        LATITUDE = new ArrayList<String>();
        LONGITUDE = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("cities");
            QuestionForSliderMenu = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d("Cities: ", array.toString());
            for (int my = 0; my <= array.length(); my++) {

                JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(my);

                String name = c.getString("name");
                String state = c.getString("state");
                String latitude = c.getString("latitude");
                String longitude = c.getString("longitude");

                  NAME.add(name);
                  STATE.add(state);
                  LATITUDE.add(latitude);
                  LONGITUDE.add(longitude);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Here's the custom adapter I am using.

Step2:

```
    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private int lastPosition = -1;
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<ModelClass> name;
        private ArrayList<ModelClass> state;
        private ArrayList<ModelClass> latitude;
        private ArrayList<ModelClass> longitude;
        private ArrayList<ModelClass> MainItems;
        private ArrayList<String> mainList;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelClass> name,
                ArrayList<ModelClass> state, ArrayList<ModelClass> latitude,
                ArrayList<ModelClass> longitude) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
            this.name = name;
            this.state = state;
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public MyAdapter(Context applicationContext,
                ArrayList<String> questionForSliderMenu1) {

            super();

            this.mainList = questionForSliderMenu1;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return STATE.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_row, null);
            }

            ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.customimageView1);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customtextView1);
            TextView state = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customtextView2);
            TextView latitude = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Latitude);
            TextView longitude = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Longitude);

            try {
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                name.setText(NAME.get(position));
                state.setText(STATE.get(position));
                latitude.setText(LATITUDE.get(position));
                longitude.setText(LONGITUDE.get(position));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

This is a method to retrieve json from assets: This is optional in your case. But for now, I have to use this for the methods above.

```
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

        String json = null;

        try {

            InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(
                    "yourjson.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }

}
```

Lastly, two xmls,

One: Your ListView layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customlistView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second: Your items for listview,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/customimageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cities"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/State"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="States"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Latitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Longitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this helps you answering your question...:)

If you like my answer and thought it was helpful, accept it please .. :)

Comment: I am grad I was able to help .. :)

Comment: was this answer helpful though

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating your own custom layout which can be inflated inside the ListView's getView method as an item and the same layout would be applied to all of them as @nikis said too.

Here is an easy to understand and a working example for your need. :)

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Please include at least the basics of the article in question, so that if the article goes away, there's still an answer.

Comment: At least give him some kind of basic info and not just giving a link to tutorial.